# More efficient select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 I have a table containing data from download activity at our web site. I have made a tool to manually match each company from the web download table to accounts in our customer database. Not all downloaders are actually belonging to a customer company. Those non customers are matched to a default account.

A company name in the download table may be spelled in many different ways, so many different names are matched to the same account.

Companies may exist in different countries. Each company has it's own account for each country in the customer database, but there is only one default account (not one per country). To make this even more complicated, downloaders doesn't need to specify country (nothing to do about that). In those cases, the matching is made to the most probable account. The country field will in these case contain an empty space. So far, so good.

The problem comes when I want to list those companies from webDownloadTable that are not matched with existing accounts (or to the default account), that is: Does not exist in accountMatchingTable.

The most important columns in webDownloadTable are:

```
webDownloadTable(
ID int not null
webCompanyName varchar(200), 
webCountryName varchar(200), 
item integer(8),
......,
...
);
```

Primary key is `ID`.

The matching table looks like this:

```
accountMatchingTable(
AccountID int(8),
matchedCompanyName varchar(200),
matchedCountryName varchar(200),
......,
...
);
```

Primary key is `(AccountID, matchedCompanyName, matchedCountryName)`.

The tables seem to be indexed in a good way.

I have made a SQL select that actually works, but as the number of rows grow, it will get very slow. It picks the top 15 rows where the company name + country is not matched:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TOP 15 webCompanyName, webCountryName
FROM    webDownloadTable
WHERE   (webCompanyName + webCountryName NOT IN
        (SELECT matchedCompanyName + matchedCountryName FROM accountMatchingTable)  /*The combination of name and country from the matching table*/
)
    AND
    (webCompanyName + ' ' NOT IN
        (SELECT matchedCompanyName + matchedCountryName FROM accountMatchingTable)  /*The combination of name and an empty space from the matching table (see §. below)*/
    )
ORDER BY webCompanyName, webCountryName;
```

§. Need this part to pick those cases where country field is open (see explanation above).

Are there anyone out there who can help me create a more efficient select?

Comment: "The tables seem to be indexed in a good way." What other indexes are on the accountMatchingTable? (At present, it looks as though the existing query can't use any indexes on this table.)

Comment: The fields used in the select are also indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about by removing the two sub queries like so:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TOP 15 a.webCompanyName, a.webCountryName
FROM    webDownloadTable a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN accountMatchingTable b
    ON a.webCompanyName + a.webCountryName = b.webCompanyName + b.webCountryName
    OR a.webCompanyName + ' ' = b.webCompanyName + b.webCountryName
WHERE b.webCompanyName IS NULL
ORDER BY webCompanyName, webCountryName
```

Comment: Agreed, doing a LEFT-JOIN, then looking for null is much more efficient than doing sub-selects applied to every row being attempted

Comment: @DaveSexton - you've missed out the `ORDER BY` clause - without it, the `TOP 15` is meaningless.

Comment: @DaveSexton And I've removed my -1 :-)

Comment: Thanks to @DaveSexton. The response time was reduced from 1 min 45 sec. to 1 sec. That's what I call improvement!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 15 webCompanyName,
                       webCountryName
FROM   webDownloadTable
       LEFT OUTER JOIN accountMatchingTable
         ON webDownloadTable.webCompanyName = accountMatchingTable.matchedCompanyName
            AND (webDownloadTable.webCountryName = accountMatchingTable.matchedCountryName
                  OR accountMatchingTable.matchedCountryName = ' ')
WHERE  accountMatchingTable.matchedCompanyName IS NULL
ORDER  BY webCompanyName,
          webCountryName;
```

I'm not convinced about the `DISTINCT TOP 15` though - it might be better to do the distinct in a subquery and then select `TOP 15` from that, or use a ranking function partitioning by your two values.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a `NOT EXISTS` clause, like so:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TOP 15 webCompanyName, webCountryName
FROM    webDownloadTable d
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM accountMatchingTable m
 WHERE m.matchedCompanyName = d.webCompanyName AND
       m.matchedCountryName in (d.webCountryName, ' ')
)
ORDER BY webCompanyName, webCountryName;
```

By joining on the company name and country name *separately* (instead of as a single, concatenated string), it should be possible to make use of any suitable existing indexes.

Comment: +1 - I went for joining on the individual columns too. Shame the accepted answer doesn't :-(